# Obtener lista de valores mas repetidos en una lista anidada en Python

Tags: python, lista

Buen día a todos.

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo la siguientes lista:

```
Ventas = [
    [1, 1, 5, '27/10/2020', 0],
    [2, 1, 5, '28/10/2020', 0],
    [3, 2, 5, '14/06/2020', 0],
    [4, 2, 5, '12/09/2020', 0],
    [5, 2, 5, '11/02/2020', 0],
    [6, 3, 5, '14/03/2020', 0],
    [7, 3, 4, '11/05/2020', 0],
    [8, 3, 4, '17/06/2020', 0],
    [9, 4, 4, '12/07/2020', 0],
    [10, 4, 4, '27/06/2020', 0],
    [11, 2, 3, '10/11/2019', 1],
    [12, 3, 5, '21/07/2020', 0],
    [13, 3, 4, '21/07/2020', 0],
    [14, 3, 5, '11/06/2020', 0],
    [15, 3, 5, '11/06/2020', 0],
    [16, 3, 5, '20/05/2020', 0],
    [17, 3, 5, '15/05/2020', 0],
    [18, 3, 5, '02/05/2020', 0]]
```

Como podría crear una lista que contengan con los 3 números que más se repiten del subindice[1] de cada elemento de la lista.

Comment: Estas preguntas siempre acaban cerradas porque parece que estés pidiendo que te hagan una tarea. Mi recomendación es que la edites y añadas que código has intentado hacer, etc..

Por otro lado recorre toda la lista y crea un mapa donde la key sea el número y el valor sea un contador que vas sumando cada vez que aparece. Al final lo ordenas por el contador y te quedas los 3 primeros.

Answer (score 0):

El problema planteado sirve para ilustrar el manejo de listas en Python.

El primer paso es separar los elementos de interés de la lista de entrada. También los necesito ordenados para lo que viene:

```
a = sorted([x[1] for x in ventas])
```

produce esta lista:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

`itertools` es una útil libreria que contiene la función `groupby`, que usaremos para agrupar los valores:

```
pares = [(valor, sum(1 for x in ocurrencias)) for valor, ocurrencias in itertools.groupby(a)]
```

`groupby` produce una lista de tuplas. Cada tupla contiene el valor encontrado (1, 2, 3 o 4) y un iterador. Este iterador devuelve los elementos con dicho valor. Por tanto, para saber cuantas veces ocurre un valor, hay que recorrer el iterador sumando uno en cada pasada. Esto lo hacemos `sum(1 for x in ocurrencias)`: creamos un lista de "1" (uno por cada ocurrencia del valor) y luego sumamos la lista completa, lo que da el total de ocurrencias.

Con todo, ahora `pares` tiene esto:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 10), (4, 2)]
```

Es una lista desordenada de tuplas. El primer elemento es el valor, el segundo es el número de veces que aparece.

Usaremos `sorted` nuevamente, pero ordenando en reversa. Como estamos comparando tuplas, escribiremos una función que las compare por su segundo elemento y la pondremos en un lambda:

```
sorted(pares, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Esto nos devuelve la lista de pares ordenados, de los cuales sólo me interesan los tres primeros elementos. Usare rebanado de listas:

```
sorted(pares, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
```

Esa es una lista de pares; sólo me interesan los valores, no las ocurrencias:

```
lista = [valor for valor, ocurrencias in sorted(pares, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]]
```

Produce:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

**Groupby**

itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)

> Crea un iterador que retorna claves consecutivas y grupos del
> iterable. key es una función que calcula un valor clave para cada
> elemento. Si no se especifica o es None, key es una función de
> identidad por defecto y retorna el elemento sin cambios. Generalmente,
> el iterable necesita estar ordenado con la misma función key.

**sorted**

sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)

> Retorna una nueva lista ordenada a partir de los elementos en iterable.
>
> Tiene dos argumentos opcionales que deben ser especificados como argumentos de palabra clave.
>
> `key` especifica una función de un argumento que es empleada para extraer una clave de comparación de cada elemento en iterable (por ejemplo, key=str.lower`). El valor por defecto es ``None (compara los
> elementos directamente).
>
> `reverse` es un valor boleado. Si está puesto a `True`, entonces la lista de elementos se ordena como si cada comparación fuera reversa

Answer (score 0):

En estos casos podemos tambien utilizar [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) para facilitar enormemente el trabajo.

```
import pandas as pd

# creamos un dataframe con esos valores y como índice ponemos la columna 0
df = pd.DataFrame(data=Values).set_index(0)

# 1. agrupamos por la columna 1
# 2. contamos los elementos en cada grupo
# 3. ordenamos las filas en orden descendente
most_repeated = df.groupby(1).size().sort_values(ascending=False)

# obtenemos una serie, y reiniciamos el índice para tener un dataframe
most_repeated = most_repeated.reset_index()

# cambiamos el nombre de las columnas para que se vea bonito
most_repeated.columns = ['columna_1', 'repeticiones']
```

Y listo.

```
    columna_1   repeticiones
0       3           10
1       2           4
2       4           2
3       1           2
```